# Fan speed control using relays

Tags: relay, latching

I would like to control the speed of ac 240 vac fan using capacitors as shown in the diagram below. Since the project is an ESP32 based fan speed controller, the rotary switch in the schematic will be replaced with relays as shown in diagram. There would be 5 states as follows OFF, Speed 1 to 4. Do we need 4 relays to accomplish this or can we do it with 2 or 3 relays ? I was told that we could accomplish using just 2 relays and I am unable to figure out how.

[image: speed control circuit]

[image]

Comment: So control with relays or capacitors?

Comment: The 2.2k resistor in series really limits the amount of power you’ll get through this circuit.

Answer (score 1):

> I was told that we could accomplish using just 2 relays and I am unable to figure out how.

You were told wrong. With two relays, you can only have 4 states. Just think about how many combinations of two ON and OFF states there are. Four: OFF-OFF, OFF-ON, ON-OFF, ON-ON.

Since there are five states, at minimum it's three binary digits, so three relays are needed.

Note that all you're really switching from speeds 1 to 3 is the capacitor value. The rest of the circuit is the same. The capacitor value can be changed by paralleling capacitors.

So:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuE0Yw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Relay states:

- Off: RLY1 off, RLY2 off, RLY3 off
- Low: RLY1 on, RLY2 off, RLY3 off
- Medium: RLY1 off, RLY2 on, RLY3 off
- High: RLY1 on, RLY2 on, RLY3 off
- Full: RLY3 on, other relays no-care

But there's another thing we could do: instead of having 4 speeds, if only 3 speeds would be sufficient, then two relays would do the job:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTzhWA.png)</sup>

- Off: RLY1 off, RLY2 off
- Low: RLY1 on, RLY2 off
- Medium: RLY1 off, RLY2 on
- High: RLY1 on, RLY2 on

Since fans have high rotational inertia, if you could use solid-state relays (SSRs), you can alternate between the "Low" and "Medium" states quickly - say once per mains cycle - to get the fifth state you'd have previously had.

> the rotary switch in the schematic will be replaced with relays as shown in diagram

Don't assume the circuit from the website you found is working with your fan. You'll have to test it and adjust values and figure out dissipation across R1 and R2 to rate these parts properly, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The relays are just selecting different loads that change the phase of the current to the load (fan). You could use 2 or several different capacitance values. The selector switch just selects which circuit to put in series with the load (fan).

If you found a relay with a selector you could have it be on or run at a different speed, or you could do two different speeds (lower circuit). Make sure the relay is properly rated for voltage and current load.

There are even relays that have more than two selections, or you could use two relays.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKCj9a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: There's no 'off' position.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum number of relays required is three.

[image]